# How do you convert this AS2 code to AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript-2

I am working on my AS3 and I am stuck. this code was in my AS2 file. How do you convert this code to AS3? When I set as AS3 and publish, this error message appears:

> Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 6
>   1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Color.

Please help.... :(

```
i=0;
function cogalt() {
i++;
mc.duplicateMovieClip("mc"+i, i);
//
var my_color:Color = new Color(_root["mc"+i]);
_root["mc"+i].renk1=random(255);
_root["mc"+i].renk2=random(255);
_root["mc"+i].renk3=random(255);
my_color.setRGB(_root["mc"+i].renk1<<16 | _root["mc"+i].renk2<<8 | _root["mc"+i].renk3 );
//
_root["mc"+i]._x = tiklax;
_root["mc"+i]._y = tiklay;
//
_root["mc"+i].deger2 = random(2);
//
_root["mc"+i].ziplama = 1+random(10);
_root["mc"+i]._width = _root["mc"+i]._height = 1+random(10);
//
if (_root["mc"+i].deger2 == 0) {
    _root["mc"+i].degerx = -(1+random(4));
} else {
    _root["mc"+i].degerx = +(1+random(4));
}
_root["mc"+i].onEnterFrame = function() {
    this.ziplama -=1;
    this._y-= this.ziplama;
    this._x += this.degerx;
    this._alpha -= 4;
    if (this._alpha<0) {
        delete this.onEnterFrame;
        removeMovieClip(this);
    }
};
      }
      mc.startDrag(true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.
Here's a link about setting a MovieClip’s color dynamically, AS2 to AS3 : 
http://evolve.reintroducing.com/2008/02/26/as2-to-as3/as2-%E2%86%92-as3-setting-a-movieclips-color/

2.
You will also bump into another issue. There is no duplicateMovieClip() in as3.

You will have to create a MovieClip's subclass and link it to the graphics you want to duplicate. Don't forget to select "Export for Actionscript" when you create that subclass.

then you will have

```
var mc:MovieClip = new SubclassOfMovieClip()
addChild(mc)
```

And then you'll probably have to save every instance into an Array/Vector so you can keep references to the objects.

3.
Adding listeners in as3 goes from this

```
mc.onEnterFrame=function(){}
```

to this

```
mc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onEnterFrame)

function onEnterFrame(evt:Event){}
```

Comment: What library are you talking about? Also you cannot just pick `fl.motion.Color` as a subsitute without further changes, its constructor expects totally different values than the AS2 `Color` class, also it has no `setRGB()` method.

Comment: Then this should help you : " AS2 → AS3: Setting A MovieClip’s Color Dynamically " http://evolve.reintroducing.com/2008/02/26/as2-to-as3/as2-%E2%86%92-as3-setting-a-movieclips-color/

Comment: I know, but you should put that in your answer.

Comment: Done. Thank's, i'm new here :).